# bash works alone but fails when running in screen

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I have this bash script that starts with

```
for d in /data/mydata/*; do
    echo $d
    filepath=$(echo $d | tr "/" "\n")
    pathArr=($filepath)       # fails here
    echo ${pathArr[-1]}
```

It runs fine when I just call in on command line

```
./run_preprocess.sh
```

but when I run it using screen

```
screen -dmSL run_preproc ./run_preprocess.sh
```

it fails on that pathArr line

```
./run_preproc.sh: 7: ./run_preproc.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")
```

is there something I need to do to protect the script code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, looks like you're running your script with POSIX `sh`, not `bash`. Arrays are undefined in [POSIX `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

To fix this, add a proper hashbang to your script (e.g. `/usr/bin/env bash`, or run the script directly with Bash interpreter (e.g. `/bin/bash script.sh`).

---

In addition (unrelated to the problem at hand), your script (or the snippet posted) has several potential issues:

- variables should be quoted to prevent globbing and word splitting (e.g. consider `d` - one of your files - containing `*` -- `echo $d` will include a list of all files, since `*` will be expanded)
- splitting into array with `($var)` is done on any `IFS` character, not just newlines. `IFS` includes a space, tab and newline by default. Use of `read -a` or `mapfile` is recommended over `($var)`.

Finally, if all you're trying is get the last component in path (filename), you should consider using [`basename(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
$ basename /path/to/file
file
```

or [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) syntax of Bash parameter expansion:

```
$ path=/path/to/file
$ echo "${path##*/}"
file
```

Comment: wow, that basename solution never surfaced when I was googling. works great!